# How can we change root password?

Tags: rhel, password

If we don't know the root password and don't have root access to the machine, how can we change the root password?

Comment: This is a often asked question, have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here are a few ways I can think of, from the least intrusive to the most intrusive.

## Without Rebooting

**With sudo:** if you have `sudo` permissions to run `passwd`, you can do:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Enter *your* password, then enter a new password for root twice. Done.

**Editing files**: this works in the unlikely case you don't have full `sudo` access, but you *do* have access to edit `/etc/{passwd,shadow}`. Open `/etc/shadow`, either with `sudoedit /etc/shadow`, or with `sudo $EDITOR /etc/shadow`. Replace root's password field (all the random characters between the second and third colons `:`) with your own user's password field. Save. The local has the same password as you. Log in and change the password to something else.

These are the easy ones.

## Reboot Required

**Single User mode**: This was just explained by Renan. It works if you can get to GRUB (or your boot loader) and you can edit the Linux command line. It doesn't work if you use Debian, Ubuntu, and some others. Some boot loader configurations require a password to do so, and you must know that to proceed. Without further ado:

1. Reboot.
2. Enter boot-time password, if any.
3. Enter your boot loader's menu.
4. If single user mode is available, select that (Debian calls it ‘Recovery mode’).
5. If not, and you run GRUB:

   1. Highlight your normal boot option.
   2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter edit mode. You may be asked for a GRUB password there.
   3. Highlight the line starting with `kernel` or `linux`.
   4. Press <kbd>e</kbd>.
   5. Add the word ‘single’ at the end. (don't forget to prepend a space!)
   6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and boot the edited stanza. Some GRUBs use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, some use <kbd>b</kbd>. It says which one it is at the bottom of the screen.

Your system will boot up in single user mode. Some distributions won't ask you for a root password at this point (Debian and Debian-based ones do). You're root now. Change your password:

```sh
mount / -o remount,rw
passwd # Enter your new password twice at the prompts
mount / -o remount,ro
sync # some people sync multiple times. Do what pleases you.
reboot
```

and `reboot`, or, if you know your normal runlevel, say `telinit 2` (or whatever it is).

**Replacing `init`**: superficially similar to the single user mode trick, with largely the same instructions, but requires much more prowess with the command line. You boot your kernel as above, but instead of `single`, you add `init=/bin/sh`. This will run `/bin/sh` in place of `init`, and will give you a **very** early shell with almost no amenities. At this point your aim is to:

1. Mount the root volume.
2. Get `passwd` running.
3. Change your password with the `passwd` command.

Depending on your particular setup, these may be trivial (identical to the instructions for single user mode), or highly non-trivial: loading modules, initialising software RAID, opening encrypted volumes, starting LVM, et cetera. Without `init`, you aren't running dæmons or any other processes but `/bin/sh` and its children, so you're pretty literally on your own. You also don't have job control, so be careful what you type. One misplaced `cat` and you may have to reboot if you can't get out of it.

**Rescue Disk**: this one's easy. Boot a rescue disk of your choice. Mount your root filesystem. The process depends on how your volumes are layered, but eventually boils down to:

```sh
 # do some stuff to make your root volume available.
 # The rescue disk may, or may not do it automatically.
 mkdir /tmp/my-root
 mount /dev/$SOME_ROOT_DEV /tmp/my-root
 $EDITOR /tmp/my-root/etc/shadow
 # Follow the `/etc/shadow` editing instructions near the top
 cd /
 umount /tmp/my-root
 reboot
```

Obviously, `$SOME_ROOT_DEV` is whatever block device name is assigned to your root filesystem by the rescue disk and `$EDITOR` is your favourite editor (which may have to be `vi` on the rescue system). After the `reboot`, allow the machine to boot normally; root's password will be that of your own user. Log in as root and change it immediately.

## Other Ways

Obviously, there are countless variations to the above. They all boil down to two steps:

1. Get root access to the computer (catch-22 — and the real trick)
2. Change root's password somehow.

Comment: Anyway to do this remotely? Assuming that SSH got shutdown.

Comment: Without SSH (or, presuming any of the other, scarily insecure methods like rsh or telnet), you don't have remote access to the machine, so you can't change the password. Unless of course the target computer has a known remotely exploitable issue which can help you somehow spawn a shell. The thought terrifies me more than a telnet daemon running on it. :)

Comment: So I would have to physically teleport there to fix it?

Comment: WRT "Change root's password somehow", see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168422/25985

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, your question has been discussed on Quora: [*What is a way to hack a computer system remotely?*](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-way-to-hack-a-computer-system-remotely).

Answer (score 7):

This should work on just about any distro, I think.

If you can access the root partition from another system, e.g. a live CD, you can as root from there edit `/etc/shadow`; first you have to `chmod u+w shadow`.  Find the entry for `root`, it's probably the first one and looks something like this:

```
root:$6$asdG0[..etc...]ae/:15666:0:99999:7:::
```

Erase everything between the first two colons so you end up with:

```
root::15666:0:99999:7:::
```

Then `chmod u-w shadow`.  You can now reboot the system and root will have no password.  You can just type `root` at the login prompt and it won't ask for one.  You can then use `passwd` to set one.

To be extra careful:

- Create a backup copy of `/etc/shadow` first.
- Don't log in as anyone but root until you've set a new password.  This is not critical, but guards against the theoretical possibility of unprivileged malware making some kind of [hail mary pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass) ("Hey, maybe there's no root password...").  Kinda far-fetched IMO.

Comment: That will work, but boy does it make me \*cringe\* to remove the password on a root account. I take it Ubuntu doesn't drop you in a root shell in runlevel 1? Or wouldn't a better idea be to run `passwd` in a chroot environment from the live CD?

Comment: If you feel safer trying those other methods first, go ahead.  But as long as you don't leave the system without a root password, this should be fine.  There wouldn't be a point in  malware that tried to exploit this, because if it were running at boot, it already has root privileges anyway.  So don't log in as anyone else first, I guess (might be a problem on systems that don't allow root in via the display manager, unless you can switch to console).  Even then it seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: @SailorCire ^^^

Comment: I'm very doubtful about the malware possibility as well. However, the idea behind what I suggested is that it prohibits the "Oh I'll change it later, because it works now" type of mentality that a lot of us fall in to.

Comment: You can also refer to [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow) for ways to manually generate a password for `/etc/shadow`

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the tags I take that you're using RHEL, but this solution should work equally well for all distros.

If the root password is forgotten, you can boot in single-user mode and use this to change the password. This approach is described in [the Red Hat step-by-step guide](https://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-q-and-a-root-passwd.html):

1. Enter the GRUB menu and press <kbd>e</kbd> .
2. Choose the line that begin with `kernel`, press <kbd>e</kbd> again.
3. On the end of this line, put `single`. Then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd>oot from it.

You will eventually get to a prompt where you can type `passwd root` and change the password. Then type `reboot` to reboot the system.

Comment: This will work only if you don't have any boot passwd.

Comment: And if you're not using /sbin/sulogin for single-user shell (it will prompt for root's password).

Comment: If you can get to the file system you can edit `/boot/grub/grub.conf` to remove the bootloader password and `/etc/inittab` to change the single-user shell to something like /bin/sh (cc @pradeepchhetri)