# How to set password for users in AIX using single line command?

Tags: password, aix, useradd

[image]Is there any way in which I can set the password for a newly created user account in AIX in a one line command?
I don't want to give any prompt to the user. If there is a command, it should set the password to that user without asking anything on the screen.
I need to use that command in another technology like Java/.Net. I need to create the accounts with password on a AIX machine at run time by executing one line of code where I can pass parameters.
Suppose a user is giving a username in the text box of a Java application and in the background the command needs to be executed which will create the user accounts(with the password) at a remote AIX server. I am successful to add a user account, but setting the password is something where I am stuck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `chpasswd`

> The chpasswd command administers users' passwords. The root user can
>   supply or change users' passwords specified through standard input.
>   Each line of input must be of the following format.
>
> username:password Only root users can set passwords with this command.

**Example 1:**

```
echo username:password | chpasswd
```

**Example 2:**

Also for security you can pass [encrypted password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow/81248#81248) to `chpasswd`

```
# Create Password in Encrpyted Form Using below command
# perl -e'print crypt("YourPassword", "salt")' ; echo -e

echo username:cryptedPass | chpasswd -e
```

Comment: @tbp_09 can you please accept ans as correct :)

Comment: Any idea how can I do the same thing for su command. Assume I have a root password and i want to change to root mode without giving any prompt so that i can run/invoke scripts from remote server using java or .net

Comment: have take look at expect tool http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm

Comment: also check some su trick in this link vladz.devzero.fr/002_su-stdin.php

Comment: Thanks for suggesting vladz.devzero.fr/002_su-stdin.php 

I can try something like that.

Comment: I tried expect command but it is not helping me to understand how it will work. what i am trying is as below:

#!/usr/bin/expect
su
expect "Password:"
send "xyz"

Comment: My understanding on this command is that when it hits su command (it may get in waiting status) and expect command reads Password from su prompt and it will send my password (xyz) to the prompt.
here the problem is i am getting error:invalid command name "su"
    while executing
"su"
    (file "testSample1.sh" line 2)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6204664/

Comment: Thanks for that link Rahul. That works if i have spawn command. I need to run that on AIX and it gives me an error "spawn not found".

Comment: can you please show me screen shot of that error, if possible show me your script also

Comment: I have added a screen shot with question. Please let me know what is wrong here. Well i couldn't find any other place to add it so thought to add that in question itself

Comment: earlier I used to get spawn not found error but now something new came up. it shows line of code and nothing happens. I have root password using which I am creating the new account but no luck in that.

Comment: show the code,talk is less

Comment: I have added that to question. as image

Comment: Mysu.sh should contains only `/usr/bin/su -`

Comment: then in same script use `send useradd testuser2`