# Adding an account via SSH not working with openssl

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, ssh, openssl, useradd

I am trying to add a user account to my remote server (running on Ubuntu 22.04) via SSH using below script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

protect="y"
ssh -i ssh_key root@server.ip <<END
   sudo deluser testuser
   if [[ "$protect" =~ ^[yY]*$ ]]; then sudo useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 "password") testuser && echo "User added successfully"; fi
END

read -n 1 -srp "Press any key to exit."
```

The confirmation message `User added successfully` is showing and the user is added normally. Except I can't login to that account with these credentials.

When I try to execute these commands one by one directly on the server, everything works fine and I can login to that account, so I assumed it would be some quotes escaping issue, and I tried some variantes including:

```
\""password"\"
"\"password"\"
\""password\""
"\"password\""
```

But none worked.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command has a different output every time you run it. I use this command [from this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow) to demonstrate the problem:

```
openssl passwd -6 -salt xyz  password
```

The variables starting with `$` in the output will be substituted:

```
$ openssl passwd -6 -salt xyz  password
$6$xyz$ShNnbwk5fmsyVIlzOf8zEg4YdEH2aWRSuY4rJHbzLZRlWcoXbxxoI0hfn0mdXiJCdBJ/lTpKjk.vu5NZOv0UM0
$ bash << EOF
echo $(openssl passwd -6 -salt xyz password)
EOF
/lTpKjk.vu5NZOv0UM0
```

You could run the `openssl` command on the remote host:

```
#!/bin/bash

protect="y"
if [[ "$protect" =~ ^[yY]*$ ]]; then 
   ssh -i ssh_key root@server.ip 'sudo useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 "password") testuser && echo "User added successfully"'
fi


read -n 1 -srp "Press any key to exit."
```

Note the difference between:

```
$ ssh HOST 'echo "$(openssl passwd -6 -salt xyz  password)"'
$ ssh HOST echo "$(openssl passwd -6 -salt xyz  password)"
```