How to adduser in a mounted partition without chrooting?
I would like to add a user in an SD image with an ARM Linux. Since my host computer is x86, I cannot just chroot into the mounted image. Is there a way to add a user to a filesystem at a relative path, with adduser or useradd or somehow else?

Just edit the corresponding /path/to/mount/etc/{passwd,group,shadow} files directly? To generate the hash of the password for shadow, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81240/70524

indeed! And mkdir /home/user with chown 1000:1000 /home/user. Thanks. I'll test it soon.
