# NCR unix system v/386 release 4 recover root password

Tags: password, root

we have NCR 3455 system from long time as attached all information for server (images)  ,
so  we need your help to assist us to get root password which lost it , really we appreciate your efforts  if you can send us the procedure for resting the administrator (root) password
which this server handle data base application writing in COBOL language

your fast response and concerns highly appreciated[image]

[image]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Reviewers: This question is not about Linux thus not a duplicate (at least not of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/how-can-we-change-root-password).

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the installation media and then mount the disk and edit `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` if needed.

If you don't have the media, try to connect the disk to another system which can mount an old `sysv-ufs` in `rw` mode.

Comment: You may need to provide precise instructions to do this with SVR4 machine