# Fedora 20 stuck in Emergency Mode

Tags: fedora

My laptop which ran Fedora 20 fine until this morning is now stuck in emergency mode. I have not set a root password and I cannot proceed beyond the initial prompt. Attempting to continue in default mode (ctrl d) just returns me to the emergency boot prompt. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Use a live CD and [set the root password as empty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168422/25985).